# Chinese input problem - Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ibus, input-language, input-method, chinese

I am trying to make Chinese input work in Ubuntu 17.10. I installed the language but the input doesn't work.

> Current configuration for the input method:
>
> - Active configuration: ibus (normally missing)
> - Normal automatic choice: ibus (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
> - Override rule:
> - Current override choice:  (en_US)
> - Current automatic choice: ibus
> - Number of valid choices: 3 (normally 1)
> - The override rule is defined in `/etc/default/im-config`.
> - The configuration set by `im-config` is activated by re-starting X.
> - Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
> - Available input methods: `ibus fcitx xim`
>
> Unless you really need them all, please make sure to install only one input method tool.

Comment: Did you add a Chinese input method, such as SunPinyin?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use Chinese input on ubuntu:

1. In **Language Support > Install/RemoveLanguages** add **Chinese**
2. Install `ibus` framework

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-clutter ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-qt4
   ```
3. Start ibus framework

   ```
   sudo im-config -s ibus
   ```
4. Install ibus-pinyin

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin
   ```
5. Configure

   **Settings > Region & Language > Input Source**

   Click <kbd>+</kbd> and click **Chinese** and click **Chinese(pinyin)**
6. Restart, Done!

Comment: Good answer... I skipped `ibus-clutter ibus-gtk` ... etc and it didn't work :P